# Plot xy chart with datasets derived from value range

Tags: excel, charts, scatter-plot

I have an Excel worksheet with 3 columns: x, y and data

x and y are coordinates, data is a floating point value (0-10)

I want to plot 10 series on an xy chart where each series is defined by the values in the data column.

So, series 1 comprises all those rows where the data column values are >= 0 and < 1; series 2 comprises all those rows where the data column values are >= 1 and < 2; etc.

I can obviously generate 10 separate tables from the initial table but is there a way to plot this from that initial table directly?

Comment: Would a helper column be ok to use?

Comment: I’d thought about adding 10 additional pairs of x,y columns, conditionally populated from the initial x,y columns, based on the values in the data column, then basing the 10 series on those additional x,y columns. That would work but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Use `ROUNDDOWN(<data>,0)` in a helper columns. Then filter for the desired value in that column. The chart should only show data from visible rows

Answer (score 0):

To plot ten series in a scatter chart, the data needs to be in ten separate ranges. That can easily be achieve with formulas. You don't need to duplicate the X values for each series. There can be gaps in the data table.

[image]